# Create component directory with all necessary files in a few clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I work with React and typical app structure, where I have `src/components` directory and where I store React components.

I want to simplify a way of creating new components. I want in a few clicks or in one command create a component directory with all necessary files included. And each file should have its own template.

Like:

```
src/
  components/
    ExampleComponent/
      index.ts 
      ExampleComponent.tsx 
      ExampleComponent.test.tsx
      ExampleComponent.stories.tsx
      ExampleComponent.scss
```

Is there any way to solve this task? Maybe WebStorm or VScode has templates like this?

Comment: From a quick google https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Huuums.vscode-fast-folder-structure

Comment: I've seen it done with Bash scripts before, but your question is too broad. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write your own bash script to be able to do this without too much trouble.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create directory and all files
mkdir $1
cd $1
touch index.ts
touch $1.tsx
touch $1.test.tsx
touch $1.stories.tsx
touch $1.scss
```

It would probably be a good idea to add some error checking to the script like making sure it is given a command line argument, but that should give you something to start with.